# Hava a status view/frame on the foreground all the time

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there an easy way in Android to have a layout which is always on the foreground, independent of the Activities which have focus.

I need a debugging view which needs to be updated every second, and needs to be visible but does not interact with the user (normal App operation even behind the layout is desired).

Any pointers on how to best do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at floating views like https://github.com/ProSpartan/DTTWT_Solver/tree/master/src/com/prospartan/dttwtsolver and https://github.com/EatHeat/FloatingExample